# JordanDecomposition in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the Jordan Decomposition in Mathematica for 
$$
A=\left(
\begin{matrix}
2& -5& 8&-12\\
1& -2& 4&-8\\
0&0&2&-5\\
0&0&1&-2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

I used

```
JordanDecomposition[{{2, -5, 8, 12}, {1, -2, 4, -8}, {0, 0, 2, -5}, {0, 0, 1, -2}}]
```

But it returns

> {{{2 - I, 
>      AlgebraicNumber[-I, {0, -(1/3)}] - 
>       I (AlgebraicNumber[-I, {0, -(1/6)}] + 
>          I AlgebraicNumber[-I, {7/6, 1/3}]), 2 + I, 
>      AlgebraicNumber[I, {0, -(1/3)}] + 
>       I (AlgebraicNumber[I, {0, -(1/6)}] - 
>          I AlgebraicNumber[I, {7/6, 1/3}])}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 
>      I AlgebraicNumber[-I, {-(1/12), -(1/24)}] + 
>       AlgebraicNumber[-I, {-(1/24), 1/12}], 0, 
>      AlgebraicNumber[I, {-(1/24), 1/12}] + 
>       I AlgebraicNumber[I, {1/12, 1/24}]}, {0, 
>      1/24 (-I + AlgebraicNumber[-I, {0, 1}]), 0, 
>      1/24 (I + AlgebraicNumber[I, {0, 1}])}}, {{-I, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -I, 0,
>       0}, {0, 0, I, 1}, {0, 0, 0, I}}}

How can I get rid of the "AlgebraicNumber" to have a nice matrix form? I've tried `Map[MatrixForm, %]`, but it is still there.

Comment: `N@JordanDecomposition[{{2, -5, 8, 12}, {1, -2, 4, -8}, {0, 0, 2, -5}, {0, 0, 1, -2}}]`

Comment: Version 10 gives a nicer form for this, at least on the platform I tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
RootReduce@JordanDecomposition[{{2, -5, 8, 12}, {1, -2, 4, -8}, {0, 0, 2, -5}, {0, 0, 1, -2}}]

(* {
    {{2-I,4/3,2+I,4/3},{1,0,1,0},{0,-1/12-I/6,0,-1/12+I/6},{0,-I/12,0,I/12}},
    {{-I,1,0,0},{0,-I,0,0},{0,0,I,1},{0,0,0,I}}
   } *)
```

Comment: `FullSimplify@JordanDecomposition...` works, too. (+1)